# get activityInfo metaData in onCreate method

Tags: android, metadata, android-manifest, oncreate

I need to retrieve a value from the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, stored as a meta data:

```
<meta-data android:value="3" android:name="myInterestingValue" />
```

In the `onCreate` method, I call the following method:

```
private Object getMetaData(String name) {
    try {
        ActivityInfo ai = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(this.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Bundle metaData = ai.metaData; 
        if(metaData == null) {
            debug("metaData is null. Unable to get meta data for " + name);
        }
        else {
            Object value = (Object)metaData.get(name);
            return value;
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But the `metaData` is always null. Is it impossible to access the `metaData` in the `onCreate` method? i.e. The activity has not been fully initialized yet.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will need to use the flags `GET_ACTIVITIES` and `GET_META_DATA`.

```
ActivityInfo ai = getPackageManager()
        .getActivityInfo(this.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.  You have a typo, should be : ActivityInfo app = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo( this.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES|PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested, [android-metadata](https://github.com/hilljh82/metadata) is a framework that makes it easier to get metadata from the Android manifest. The way you would get the meta-data above using [android-metadata](https://github.com/hilljh82/metadata) is:

```
int val = ManifestMetadata.get (context).getValue ("myInterestingValue", Integer.class);
```

Full disclosure: I'm the creator of android-metadata.

Comment: Is it merged in androidannotations (https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) framework ?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried jasonj's answer but it doesn't work. To retrieve meta-data from manifest file, I must get the following code

```
ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
```

OR the Kotlin version:

```
val ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
val bundel = ai?.metaData
```

Comment: getApplicationInfo is used to get metadata from the <application> element. To get meta-data from <activity> element you have to use getActivityInfo as described