# ApplicationInfo metadata returning null

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have the following code:

In the manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebookApplicationId" />
```

In the code:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
        getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
if (ai.metaData != null) {
   ...
```

But the result is ai.metaData==null. Why is this happening

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500227/get-activityinfo-metadata-in-oncreate-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the latest android doc,
<meta-data> can be only contained in <activity>/<activity-alias>/<service>/ <receiver>.
So you should append meta-data in these components, not in <application> directly.

Comment: I think this is not true as per: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html

Comment: @eeeeaaii Thanks, looks google has changed the document.

Answer (score 4):

Please be careful with where your meta-data is written. for example, if your meta-data is contained in `<application></application>`, you need to call

```
getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

If it is contained in another node, you need to change `getApplicationInfo` to the relevant method, e.g. `getActivityInfo`, `getServiceInfo` etc.