# Gradle @aar dependency resolution in react-native project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I'm using an @aar dependency with `transitive=true` in `build.gradle`.  It's downloaded to the gradle cache, but isn't resolved while the app is being compiled.

It may or may not be relevant, but I'm using it in a react-native app. The other dependencies in the build are compiled without a problem.

Does anyone have experience dealing with this type of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was a react-native issue.  If you are loading a @aar dependency in a package you also need to declare it as a repository in
`android/build.gradle`
in the block

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    DESIRED_REMOTE_REPO_HERE
  }
}
```